# Are album ratings gone in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, apple-music, album, ratings

I frequently used album ratings in iTunes in the past, but it seems in iTunes 12.2, these ratings have been replaced by the heart for Apple Music.  In list view an option for 'Album Rating' is still available but uneditable, while in grid view, which I prefer there is no visible rating for either the songs or albums.  Is there any way to bring the ratings back??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Open iTunes. Click on "iTunes" in the upper left and go down to Preferences. Under the "General" tab, you can choose ratings to be "Loves," "Stars," or "Loves and Stars."

Comment: Can't find this option on iTunes 12.5.5.5 :\

Comment: @AlvaroLourenço It looks like this option is gone in 12.5.5.5 and there is now a checkbox that says "Show Stars."