# Rate a track directly from Apple Music - stars / hearts vs My Music and syncing

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I just bought my first Mac, started Apple Music subscription and moved my music library (1500 liked tracks) from spotify.

I'm trying to make some sense of rating system iTunes/Apple Music has and I think I need some clarifications.

1. When I'm listening to a track on Apple Music I can heart it but I can't star-rate it.
2. When I click on the same track and add it to My Music I can later find it in my collection on iTunes and I can see the heart. I can star-rate it.
3. But if I only heart it I can't find it in my music. It is necessary to do 2 interactions (heart&add to My Music) to find track I like later.
4. On mobile (Apple Music for Android) I can heart a track, I can browse My Music collection, but I can't add a track to it.
5. But on mobile device I can add it to a playlist, so it appears in My Music collection.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to mark music I like from any device and be able to find it later from any device.
Also, I like the feature to star rate tracks to distinct music I love from music I like.

So, my question is: **how to use starring/hearting/adding to my music correctly?***

*preferably like Apple intended it to be used to avoid complications when some features are changed

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246498/are-album-ratings-gone-in-itunes/246501#246501

Comment: @TMHahn: I know about it and enabled it at first place, but it solves only "distinct music I love from music I like" part.